# Ruby - Set age in array with multiple objects

Tags: ruby

I am  trying to figure out how to look through an array of objects, find said object by the persons name, and then use a class method to edit the age value of that object. In the example below, I am trying to set the persons age by using the .set_age method that I have configured. However, it does not return any change to any objects, and I know it's because I'm not accessing the object properly, but I can't figure out how to do so. Can anyone help me access an object in an array and then find the person by their name and then set their age?

```
class Person
  attr_accessor :name, :age, :mood
  def initialize(name, age, mood)
    @name = name
    @age = age
    @mood = mood
  end
  def set_age(amount)
    @age = amount
    self
  end
end
person1 = Person.new("John", 18, "happy")
person2 = Person.new("Jackie", 20, "happy")
person3 = Person.new("Charlie", 19, "sad")

persons_array = []
persons_array << person1
persons_array << person2
persons_array << person3

while true
  p "1. Change persons age"
  p "2. Exit"
  choice = gets.chomp
  case choice
    when "1"
      p "Name of person to change."
      person_name = gets.chomp
      p "What would you like to set their age to?"
      person_age = gets.chomp.to_i
      persons_array.each_with_index {|key, value|
        if key == person_name
          person_name.set_age(person_age)
          p "changed #{person_name} age"
          p persons_array
        end
      }
      p persons_array
    when "2"
      break
    end
  end
```

Comment: Since you're not posting Javascript I think you should get rid of those HTML comments in your question that say it is Javascript and result in a useless "Run code snippet" button.

Comment: Why do you have a `set_age` method that is almost identical to your `age=` method? Why not just use the `age=` method?

Comment: How would you go about rewriting it Jorg?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to match the `person_name` against the index of the array. When you do `persons_array.each_with_index`, you're telling Ruby that you'd like to iterate through the array and have the index of each element available to the block as well.

However, an Array is indexed by integers, so you're basically comparing the person's name from the `stdin` to an integer. You'd be better off comparing the object's actual name.

Something like:

```
found_person = persons_array.find { |person| person.name == person_name }
if found_person
  found_person.set_age(person_age)
  p "changed #{person_name} name"
end
```

Comment: You are amazing. This is just what I needed. I was in a bit over my head, but thanks to you I can see now!